# custom UITableViewCell reuse highlight issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

in the project I'm on, there is already a custom UITableViewCell and I have determined the issue is in the reuse of the cell.

These 2 methods are doing the overriding of the highlighting and selecting:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    if (self.isCellEditing == NO) {
        if (highlighted) {
            self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } else {
            self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (self.isCellEditing == NO) {
        if (selected) {
            self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } else {
            self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    } else {
        if (selected) {
            self.editImageView.image = self.editAccessorySelectedImage;
        } else {
            self.editImageView.image = self.editAccessoryImage;
        }
    }
}
```

what's happening in the app that is causing the issue is that I need to auto-scroll and select the last selected cell before the app closed on app launch (done in viewDidAppear).  This works, except for highlighting the cell, it does in fact scroll to the cell selects it, as it shows in the details view (iPad splitview setup), but the cell will not highlight.  This is a reuse issue because if the cell that needs to be scrolled to is one of the first cells that are visible at load, it will highlight but if it's a cell that's off screen and it scrolls to that cell it will select but not highlight it.

ETA: cell reuse override:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {

[super prepareForReuse];

self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
_cellEditing = NO;
_swipingToDelete = NO;
_editViewAnimated = NO;
}
```

Comment: Is the cell's prepareForReuse method is overridden?

Comment: Isn't the isCellEditing your custom property? Shouldn't that resetted in prepareForReuse?

Comment: yes it's being set, I left it out, but updated above.  I realize what the issue is, the setHighlighted: is being called by UIKit after setSelected has been called, so on dequeueReusableCell setHighlighted is called, and the highlighted Bool passed in to the overridden method is NO, which is selecting White which is overriding the red selected before.

Answer (score 0):

In the event anyone else wants a custom highlight and selected state, the fix was:

```
if (highlighted || self.isSelected)
```

this will force it to jump inside this if block since when it's selected you want it the color of the highlight and selected state (assuming they're the same color)